# C# HttpClient DefaultHeaders Authorization not being used

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

```
private HttpClient GetHttpClient()
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient()
        {
            BaseAddress = new Uri(Settings.BaseAddress)
        };

    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Settings.ApiKey);

    // client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add( "Authorization", "Basic " + Settings.ApiKey);

    return client;
}

private async Task<string> GetAccount()
{
    using (HttpClient httpClient = GetHttpClient())
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync($"/v1/accounts/{Settings.AccountNumber}");
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        string json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }

    return await Task.FromResult((string)null);
}
```

The default header is set on the instance of `HttpClient` but it is not sent with the request.

[image]

**Update: These don't work either**

```
                    string authorization = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"{Settings.ApiKey}"));
                    // is c2tfbGl2ZV9YREpEUnR2eFVhRmpyMmoydkZJTm9kemE6

                    // Firefox gets
                    // c2tfbGl2ZV9YREpEUnR2eFVhRmpyMmoydkZJTm9kemE6dW5kZWZpbmVk

                    authorization = "c2tfbGl2ZV9YREpEUnR2eFVhRmpyMmoydkZJTm9kemE6dW5kZWZpbmVk";

                    var request = WebRequest.Create($"{Settings.BaseAddress}/v1/accounts/{Settings.AccountNumber}");
                    //AuthenticationHeaderValue h = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", authorization);
                    request.Headers.Add("authorization", "Basic " + authorization);

                    string text;
                    var rr = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

                    using (var sr = new StreamReader(rr.GetResponseStream()))
                    {
                        text = sr.ReadToEnd();
                    }
```

**wget**

```
# wget --header="Authorization: Basic c2tfbGl2ZV9YREpEUnR2eFVhRmpyMmoydkZJTm9kemE6" https://api.example.com/v1/accounts/accountNumber --output-document -
```

works

Comment: In your debug image you are pointing to the `response`'s `Headers`, not the request's

Comment: The fact that you get 401 does not prove that the headers are not send. I'm almost sure that the header is actually send, but the problem is that either it is invalid or some other headers are missing. Use Fiddler or Wireshark to check what is actually send and compare it with the full successful request via Postman or some other similar tool.

Comment: you should try making a Postman/CURL request to verify that the header and request is working fine.

Comment: Works fine from `wget`, and I'm pretty sure that `response.RequestMessage.Headers` is not the _response_ headers.

Comment: Is the authorization string in the question is a real one? If so change the password for security reason.

Answer (score 0):

The fix is to add a trailing slash to the request URL.